# Normal subgroup created by a bunch of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

if I have a finite group $G$ and a bunch of elements that are the elements of a set $A$. How can I systematically calculate the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ that contains $A$? I am rather interested in a practical way how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are given a group table (or something other way of working concretely with elements) and a starting subset, one way might be to use the following algorithm:

Let $S_0$ be the given set of elements, their inverses, and the identity. Let $i=0$.

(i) Let $S_i'$ be the set of all conjugates of elements in $S_i$.

(ii) Let $S_{i+1}$ be the set of all possible products of pairs of elements in $S_i'$.

(iii) If $|S_{i+1}| = |S_i|$, stop. Otherwise, increment $i$ by $1$ and return to (i).

We need to verify that this procedure builds a normal subgroup. We first note the following:

(0) $e \in S_0$

(1)  $a, b \in S_m \implies ab \in S_{m+1}$.

(2) $a\in S_m \implies a^{-1} \in S_m$.

(3) $a \in S_m$,  $g \in G  \implies g a g^{-1} \in S_{m+1}$.

Of the above, (2) is the only one that is perhaps non-trivial. This can be shown by induction. Now, note the algorithm does terminate, since the group is finite. Suppose that the terminal set is $S_{k+1}$. Then $S_{k+1} = S_{k}$, and (0)-(3) above show $S_{k}$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: No problem -- I'm curious, are you thinking of implementing this in some sort of a computer algebra package?

Comment: no. i was just wondering whether there is a strategy to do this, if you have no idea, what the subgroup could be...

Comment: @user My strategy would be to use GAP. And if I was really curious, read the source code. The most efficient algorithm changes with group size, due to the limitations of the computer. And some group properties tend to yield nicer algorithms. Solvability often does this. Even the exact presentation of the group has an impact.

Answer (score 0):

Try the intersection of all normal subgroups that contains your subset $A$.

Comment: sorry, but this is really what I didn't want to know, because this does not help in an actual calculation.

Comment: being finite your group, all it is an easy cake

Comment: but how can I construct all normal subgroups?

Comment: alternatively use the elements of $a\in A$ and all is conjugates $gag^{-1}$ to find this smallest subgroup